# How to handle Fragments reloading in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have created an Activity with a custom footer which has 4 buttons.

Code for Footer buttons onClick:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    try
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .replace(R.id.flcontent,Tab1)
                            .commit();

                break;

            case R.id.button2:

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.flcontent,Tab2)
                        .commit();

                break;

            case R.id.button3:

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.flcontent, Tab3)
                        .commit();

                break;

            case R.id.button4:


                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.flcontent, Tab4)
                        .commit();

                break;



        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In the onCreate method of Tabs, I make a call to the server to fetch a list. 
Different Tabs have different requests.

When I click Button 2, Tab2 loads and so on till Button4, Tab4

For example when I navigate from Tab1 to Tab2: 
When I click Button2, Tab1 is replaced by Tab2 and a new list gets loaded. 
When I click Button1 back, How do I prevent calling the server again in Tab1?

Comment: make a static variable to track that if you have called server then you will not call it again

Answer (score 0):

There are lifecycle methods of an android fragment which gets called automatically everytime our fragments are replaced by other fragment.

Use the proper fragment activity lifecycle methods of the fragments which are acting as a tab in your app. e.g. when your app movies from tabl to tab2 you use the method

```
//Add the below method to your tab1 fragment
@Override
void onDetach (){
   // write code here that would tell the server to stop loading data
   // you can also use onPause and onStop
}
```

Check out fragment lifecycle methods on the android developer documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Do check the updated answer and go through the the documentation for fragments for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me is to create a Singleton class which contains all the data returned from the server for all of the tabs.

When you show lets say Tab1, you should check if there is any info for this tab in the Singleton class. If there is something, don't send a call to the server.

You can also do that by having a static data container (list, hash map, etc.) for the info from the server in each of your classes which describe a particular Tab.

I personally prefer the first way.

@KhizarHayat suggestion is like my second option described above, but just make sure that the data from the server is not deleted once the fragment is destroyed during transactions.